# How to fix issue where importing TailwindCSS by CDN works fine but installing it as a NPM dependency does not only on codesandbox.io?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, codesandbox

I've built a small notes app using Vue.js with TailwindCSS. To publish it, I've put it on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/notes-tyxbp) but due to some unknown reasons, styles does not apply. If I use CDN to import TailwindCSS, it works fine. Other configurations are same as my local environment in which it also works as expected.

Thank you! :)

Comment: how are you importing the package when you install as npm dependency? can you show in sanbox where it's failing

Comment: @kiddorails I don't where the problem is because I don't know how to debug in codesandbox.io. I don't see any warning/error in console. You should be able to fork it by following the link in the description. I think it's configuration problem with PostCSS.

Comment: What styles you are talking about, which one exactly does not work? In codesandbox I see tailwind classes in output, like text-3xl that corresponds to font-size: 1.875rem; so it looks right.

Comment: @chojnicki It works because TailwindCSS is imported through CDN. If you comment the CDN version and import it from NPM packages, it won’t work.